# Run/start both test and app with one command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

Currently I have these two script commands in `package.json`:

```
"dev": "react-scripts start",
"test": "react-scripts test",
```

Is there a way I can run both of those with a single command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In package.json scripts section define `"run:all": "npm run dev & npm run test"` and then run `npm run:all`.

`&&` will make you second command to wait until first one is executed.
`&` will not wait and will start in parallel

Comment: Yes, `"all": "yarn test & yarn dev"` did it. Thank you!